# Loop through non paramteric two-way ANOVA

Tags: r, for-loop, anova

I am having trouble looping through the `pbad2way` function from the `WRS2` package. The R documentation for this function can be found here: http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/WRS2/html/t2way.html

**Code:**

```
library(WRS2)
library(rcompanion)

data(Catbus)

for(i in 1:3){
        pbad<-pbad2way(Steps ~ Teacher + Sex + Teacher:Sex, 
     data = Catbus, 
     est = "mom", 
     nboot = 599, 
     pro.dis = T)
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try this one: `as.formula(paste(colnames(iris)[i], "~ Species + Petal.Width + Species:Petal.Width"))`. But there are a lot of other problems why your code is not working related to the `pbad2way()` function.

Comment: @Jimbou, thanks. But I get this: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer`. Something to do with `colnames`, I think. Am I wasting my time here? Do you think `sapply` might work?

Comment: No it has nothing to do with you colnames. Try this `pbad2way(Sepal.Length ~ Species + Petal.Width + Species:Petal.Width, 
         data = iris,
         est = "mom",
         nboot = 599, pro.dis = T)` and you see that your formula per se is your problem. Check the examples `?pbad2way()`

Comment: @Jimbou, you were very right and I was so wrong. I have edited my question because it was so dumb. Your first comment was correct all along. Feel free to post as the answer. Thanks!!